# XDocument removing nodes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file

```
<rows>
  <head>
    <beforeInit>
      <call command="attachHeader">
        <param>#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter</param>
      </call>
    </beforeInit>
    <afterInit>
      <call command="enablePaging">
        <param>recinfoArea</param>
      </call>
     </afterInit>
    <column width="100" align="center" type="ro" sort="server" color="undefined" id="Id">Id</column>
    <column width="100" align="center" type="ro" sort="server" color="undefined" id="NazovProjektu">NazovProjektu</column>
   </head>
</rows>
```

I'd like to remove the beforeInit and afterInit elements.

I tried

```
xml.Elements().Where(e=>e.Name == "beforeInit" || e.Name == "afterInit").Remove();
```

but no luck.

Comment: If I'd know I wouldn't ask :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you want to delete every occurence of beforeInit or afterInit you could use

```
xml.Descendants().Where(e=>e.Name == "beforeInit" || e.Name == "afterInit").Remove();
```

(descendants instead of elements).
elements() returns a list of direct child nodes, whereas descendants returns every node.

Comment: Or the short form: xml...<beforeInit>.First.Remove()

Comment: Should `e.Name` actually be `e.Name.LocalName` ?

Comment: @Stephan Schinkel how do i remove the all the head content if  BeforeInit is present ?

Answer (score 3):

If xml is a XElement, try:

```
xml.Element("head").Elements().Where(e=>e.Name == "beforeInit" || e.Name == "afterInit").Remove();
```

Otherwise, if it's an XDocument:

```
xml.Root.Element("head").Elements().Where(e=>e.Name == "beforeInit" || e.Name == "afterInit").Remove();
```

The way it is now, it's set up to look for the sub elements in `<rows>`, not `<head>`.  In other words Elements() only returns the direct children of a node.  If you want all the descendants, no matter what level, you want Descendants().